# How to play ogg file with NSpeex?

Tags: c#, .net, naudio, nspeex

I'm working on a c# project with particular needs of playing ogg file with [NSpeex](https://nspeex.codeplex.com/) Library.

How to make NSpeex to read ogg file from file path? and how to make it play and seek?

I think NAudio is needed, but I still can't figure out how...

Forgive me, I'm new to audio development, I hope someone could show me some code samples here.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".